# How to display something from local storage on a DIFFERENT Page

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am collecting values from inputs like this

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
   Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE="" id="input1"><br />
   Event Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value="" id="input2"><br />
   Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE="" id="input3"><br />
   Event Notes: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE="" id="input4"><br />
   <button onclick="storeValues(event)" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>

    <script>


function storeValues(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let storedEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Events")) || [];

    const newEventDetails = {
      name: document.getElementById('input1').value,
      dateTime: document.getElementById('input2').value,
      location: document.getElementById('input3').value,
      notes: document.getElementById('input4').value
    }
    storedEvents.push(newEventDetails);
    localStorage.setItem("Events", JSON.stringify(storedEvents));

    console.log('storedEvents', storedEvents);

}
</script>
```

I have tried to display these inputs like this

```
<h2 id='input1'>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2 id='input2'>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2 id='input3'>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2 id='input4'>&nbsp;</h2>

<!-- running script here will populate H2's with values from local storage -->
<script>
   document.getElementById('input1').value = localStorage.getItem("EventName");
   document.getElementById('input2').value = localStorage.getItem("EventDateAndTime");
   document.getElementById('input3').value = localStorage.getItem("EventLocation");
   document.getElementById('input4').value = localStorage.getItem("EventNotes");
</script>
```

However it doesn't display how would I go about getting it to display?

Comment: The second script needs to run after the storeValues function is called. Could it be run before the storeValues function, causing empty values to be fetched from localStorage?

Comment: The storage keys used in each page are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` property would be correct if you were indeed working with inputs. For an HTML element, use `innerText` (or `innerHTML` if necessary, but be aware of security risks).

```js
document.getElementById('input1').innerText = localStorage.getItem('EventName');
```